# Create factor labels in a DF using a sequence of numbers

Tags: r

I have a data.frame containing numerics. I want to create a new column within that data.frame that will house factor labels using (`letters[]`). I want these factor labels to be built from a sequence of numbers that I have, and can change every time.

For example, my original DF has 1 column `x` containing numerics, I then have a sequence of numbers (3,7,9). So I need the new `FLABEL` column to populate according to the number sequence, i.e. first 3 lines are `a`, next 4 lines `b` and so on.

```
x       FLABEL
0.23     a
0.21     a
0.19     a
0.27     b
0.25     b
0.22     b
0.15     b
0.09     c
0.32     c
0.19     d
0.17     d
```

I'm struggling with how to do this, I'm assuming some form of for-loop given that my number sequence can vary in length every time I run it So I could be populating letters a & b...or many more.

Comment: why not `DF$FLABEL <- rep(letters[1:4],c(3,4,2,2))`

Comment: because the number seq can change length & content every time I run my script

Comment: change according to what? How do you compute seq?

Comment: The seq comes from a changepoint detection im running, the script goes thru many diiferent permutations of data each time performing this task...so the solution has to be generic enough to handle whatever that seq of numbers will end up being

Comment: `rep(letters[length(seq)],seq)`. But make sure `length(seq) <= 26`

Comment: @scoa Minor correction: I think this should be `rep(letters[1:length(series)],series)` where `series <- c(3,4,2,2)` in this example.

Comment: @RHertel right, sorry about that

Comment: scoa code was giving incorrect number of dimensions, @RHertal code is throwing an error because the resulting col ends up being really long, longer than the original x column......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by @scoa, I suggest the following modified approach:

```
series <- c(3, 7, 9)
series <- c(series, nrow(DF)) # This ensures that the sequence extends to the last row of DF
series2 <- c(series[1] ,diff(series))
DF$FLABEL <- rep(letters[1:length(series2)], series2)
#> DF
#      x FLABEL
#1  0.23      a
#2  0.21      a
#3  0.19      a
#4  0.27      b
#5  0.25      b
#6  0.22      b
#7  0.15      b
#8  0.09      c
#9  0.32      c
#10 0.19      d
#11 0.17      d
```

By using `diff()` the length of each sequence is calculated based on the index numbers in the input vector `series`. In this case, the index values 3, 7, 9 are converted into the number of repetitions of subsequent letters up to the last row of the data frame and stored in `series2`: 3, 4, 2, 2.

**data**

```
text <- "x       FLABEL
         0.23     x
         0.21     x
         0.19     x
         0.27     x
         0.25     x
         0.22     x
         0.15     x
         0.09     x
         0.32     x
         0.19     x
         0.17     x"
DF <- read.table(text = text, header=T)
```

Comment: Erroring because the final difference isn't being handled...what i mean is the dataframe lables only go as far as the last seq number where it should go right to the end nrow of the original dataframe

Comment: Please check if you still obtain an error with the code in the revised post.

Comment: I got it to work by using ....end<- (nrow(x)-tail(series,1))...then....series2 <- c(series2,end). This allows the letters labelling to run right from the last diff point to the end of the dataframe..